# How to use GNUS with Gmail?

Tags: emacs, gmail, gnus

I searched for several mail clients but all are messed up. The best I could find was gnus which I managed to configure to retrieve data from Gmail. However:

1. When I read message in gnus, it is still marked as unread on gmail
2. I couldn't find how assign labels to emails
3. I couldn't find how to sort or delete messages (preferably using key binding)?

I think that my problem is that gnus uses newsgroup terminology which confuses me.

Is there any tutorial online which focus only on this?

The problem I have is how to test.

Comment: Well - there is notmuch, which has a very similar philosophy to gmail (tags, no folders) but synching these to gmail is an ongoing problem. Check out [notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm surprised by your 1, because when I read mail in gnus, they are marked read in gmail.

For the rest, gmail maps labels to IMAP folder, so

```
B m nnimap+gmail:commande
```

Will move the article to the commande label, and mark it with the commande label. GNUS will create the folder if needed.

Probably, copying the mail with `B c` will add the label, but I don't use it.

```
B m nnimap+gmail:[Gmail]/Trash
```

will put it into the trash folder, and so delete it.

Deleting it with `B Del` or using expiry (`E`) will just remove the label or archive the message. I've setup:

```
(setq gnus-parameters
      '(("nnimap\\+gmail:INBOX" (expiry-wait . 2))))
```

This will archive message marked for expiry two day after they have been received.

Comment: Can you please email me your .gnus file? I have some problems... my email is "difrequent@gmail.com"

Comment: Every thing is there: https://github.com/vanicat/emacs24-starter-kit/blob/my-change/moi/gnus-config.org beware: there are experimental change in this file.